# Calculating the share of each code, by ID

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data-frame:

```
ID  code   X  X_total
 A   456  40       40
 A   789   0       40
 B   123  75      100
 B   987  25      100
 C   789  13       91
 C   987   0       91
 C   123  35       91
 C   456  43       91
```

I want the calculate the *share* of each code (from `[123, 465, 789, 987]`), by dividing `X` by `X_total`, for each `ID`.

Expected result:

```
ID  share_123  share_456  share_789  share_987
 A       0.00       1.00       0.00       0.00
 B       0.75       0.00       0.00       0.25
 C       0.38       0.47       0.14       0.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do `crosstab`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.code, df.X ,aggfunc='sum', normalize='index').add_prefix("share_")
Out[70]: 
code       123       456       789   987
ID                                      
A     0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.00
B     0.750000  0.000000  0.000000  0.25
C     0.384615  0.472527  0.142857  0.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with your logic:

```
df.assign(k=df['X'].div(df['X_total'])).pivot("ID","code","k").fillna(0)
```

---

```
code       123       456       789   987
ID                                      
A     0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.00
B     0.750000  0.000000  0.000000  0.25
C     0.384615  0.472527  0.142857  0.00
```

Adding formatting:

```
(df.assign(k=df['X'].div(df['X_total'])).pivot("ID","code","k").fillna(0)
   .add_prefix("share_").round(2).rename_axis(None,axis=1).reset_index())

  ID  share_123  share_456  share_789  share_987
0  A       0.00       1.00       0.00       0.00
1  B       0.75       0.00       0.00       0.25
2  C       0.38       0.47       0.14       0.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with `groupby` + `unstack`

```
df['X'].div(df['X_total']).groupby([df['ID'], df['code']]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)

code       123       456       789   987
ID                                      
A     0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.00
B     0.750000  0.000000  0.000000  0.25
C     0.384615  0.472527  0.142857  0.00
```